# Error while importing RxJS operators in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am getting this error. I'm trying to use

```js
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators'
```

instead of

```js
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch'
```

But what to use instaed of `rxjs/add/operator/do` and `rxjs/add/operator/toPromise`?

Answer (score 2):

The import statements depend on the RxJS version.

RxJS 5+

```js
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
```

RxJS 6+

```js
import { catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operator';
```

The `catch` and `do` operators were replaced with `catchError` and `tap` respectively. Nothing has to be imported for `toPromise` since it isn't pipeable and invoked directly on an observable.

Also, if you're using `toPromise` you need to know that it is [being deprecated](https://indepth.dev/rxjs-heads-up-topromise-is-being-deprecated/) in RxJS 7 and will be gone in RxJS 8.

Comment: So, i dont need to use toPromise in my application?

Comment: @user13911625: As shown in the article, you could continue to convert observables to promises using `lastValueFrom` or `firstValueFrom` instead. However I'd tell you to refrain converting observables to promises unless there is an explicit need for it. Observables in general also provide more control over the stream of data.